# How to correctly implement NSFetchedResultsController.controllerDidChange()

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UIView` which has a `UITableView` along with different components. Its corresponding `UIViewController` has the `viewDidLoad()` as follows:

```
Class Foo: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* some other stuff */

        // An instance of a class implementing UITableViewData Source
        // and NSFetchedResultsController. 
        // It also contains the instance of the  
        // NSFetchedResultsController.
        self.namesTable.dataSource = self.namesTableController  
        self.namesTableController.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    }

    // For updating the table when its content changes - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.namesTable.reloadData()
    }

    /* Other functions, etc, etc.... */

}
```

This arrangement works fine: when I add/remove entries to/from the table, the table reloads.

But I don't think that this is the right way of doing it, since the **entire table is re-loaded every time** when any change occurs. Seems like an overkill.

After looking online for several hours, I am not coming with anything. Can anyone point me to the right way of doing this? or am I doing it right?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html)? It shows a typical implementation. – Also if you start a fresh "Master-Detail + Core Data Application" in Xcode you'll get the code for free.

Comment: Never realized that the Master-Detail sample can be created with Core Data! Thanks a LOT for the tip, looking into it now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is nothing "wrong" with `reloadData()` it is unnecessary to call it every time one object changes, as you stated. You can update only the content you want by implementing the other `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` functions and using `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` like so:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}


func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        break
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```